# SR backend failure on Xen for vm-start

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

One of my VM in halted on Xen Centre and when I try to start it with

```
xe vm-start vm=vm_uuid
```

it throws an error

```
There was an SR backend failure.
status: Xml.Error(_)
stdout:
stderr:
```

I am new to Xen hence any pointers on what is going wrong will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This [Citrix discussion](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/272994-xmlerror_/#comment-1492189) may help you.

Well, in my point of view just try to restart Xen API service. If didn't solve this problem, try [this one](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/272994-xmlerror_/#comment-1492373).

Thank you.